# Laravel mix can not compile import() function

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

[image]

Laravel mix can not compile import() function.

Comment: You can try to install plugin `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`

Comment: At `.babelrc` file adding that plugin `{
    "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}`

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn not working....

Comment: Can you please show `babel` version you using?

Comment: If you using `@babel/core` -> try `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` plugin instead of.

Comment: Thank you very much @QuỳnhNguyễn. It's working now with `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` plugin.

Comment: Can I post an answer?

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this `import() Unexpected token` because missing babel plugin allow parsing of import().

1. Please try to install one in either:

   - [plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import) plugin
   - [@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import) if you using @babel/core

     Example command line: `npm i babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`
2. Create or edit your `.babelrc` file in your project root.

   ```
   {
       "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
   }
   ```

And try to run your project again.

Hope this work for you and for other members.